# Which to use? Twitter Search API vs. Twitter REST API's search/tweets

Tags: api, rest, search, twitter

I'm trying to search Twitter for Tweets, and after looking over the docs, I can't tell when I should use the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) vs when I should use [search/tweets from the REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). The former is unauthenticated and the latter is authenticated - but other than that, it's not jumping out at me from the docs how one would use the 2 differently. Halp!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/history-rest-search-api), it depends entirely on the content you're trying to obtain.

> The Twitter REST API methods allow developers to access core Twitter data. This includes update timelines, status data, and user information. The Search API methods give developers methods to interact with Twitter Search and trends data. The concern for developers given this separation is the effects on rate limiting and output format.

Comment: But "core data" from REST API apparently includes search as well (see search/tweets). Still not obvious to me what's the difference (other than the difference of authenticated vs. unauthenticated calls - both of which are rate limited).

Comment: Well the article also says it's on their agenda to unify the API's, so clearly the differences aren't big enough to even warrant separate API's. From what I understand, there were two companies doing the same thing and one bought out the other. So you're probably fine using either one.